# My bot sending multiple messages, discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

To explain briefly, the code is to make already existing buttons after restart of the bot usable again, I store for this the channelId and the messageId. However, several messages are stored, therefore the foreach(), as long as only one message is stored, everything is fine when I then try to use a button, but if there are 2 or more messages, the message is sent more often, how do I fix this?

I hope anyone can help me <3

```
fs.readdir(folder, (err, files) => {
    files.forEach(file => {
        const r = fs.readFileSync(`${folder}/${file}`, { encoding: "utf-8" })
        const data = JSON.parse(r)

        const channel = client.channels.cache.get(data.channelId)
        channel.messages.fetch(data.messageId).then(async (message) => {
            const collector = message.channel.createMessageComponentCollector();

            collector.on('collect', async i => {
                if (i.customId === 'upvote') {
                    return i.channel.send({ content: 'A button was clicked!', components: [] });
                } else if (i.customId === 'downvote') {
                    return i.channel.send({ content: 'A button was clicked!', components: [] });
                }
            });
        })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You're running your token in several times. Try to `reset your token` and run it on one platform.

Comment: I do not execute my token more than once.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume it's because you have the code executing inside the `forEach`, so possibly have some sort of array outside of it and push the messages to the array, and then try to send the message channel.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).